# Linux EMC scan Lun not working

Tags: linux, storage, fdisk, scsi

We have `CX4-120 EMC SAN storage`, I expend existing `LUN` size to 20GB but now i am not able to see any cylinder changes on host `fdisk -l` output. Following command i am running to `re-scan` my hda or LUN

```
echo "1" > /sys/class/fc_host/host1/issue_lip
echo "1" > /sys/class/fc_host/host2/issue_lip
```

And then

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/scan
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/scan
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host3/scan
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host4/scan
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host5/scan
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host6/scan
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host7/scan
```

But still `fdisk -l /dev/emcpowere`  showing old cylinder size, Am i missing something? I have qlogic hda

Comment: It may be an issue with the PowerPath driver. Do you know if the actual block devices pointed to by the `emcpowere` device are updating? if you do `powermt display dev=emcpowere` it should tell you which native block devices are different paths to the same `emcpowere` LUN.

Comment: Also, fwiw, I typically use the `rescan-scsi-bus.sh` script available in the `sg3_utils` package on RHEL/CentOS rather than type all that out. Just saves time for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All above command doesn't work if you expanding existing LUN or re-scaning existing LUN.

Solution:

```
echo "1" > /sys/block/<DEVICE>/device/rescan
```

Handy script:

```
cd /dev
for DEVICE in `ls sd[a-z] sd?[a-z]`; do echo '1' > /sys/block/$DEVICE/device/rescan; done
```